# How to count number of instances of specific class in arraylist?

Tags: java, java-7

I have an array list that looks like:

```
[new Class1(), new Class2(), new Class1(), new Class1()]
```

I want to know the most efficient way to extract the number of instances of Class1 in the array list.

For the above example, I want the answer 3.

I am using Java version "1.7.0_79".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the arraylist is like below,

```
newClass1 = new Class1();

[newClass1, new Class2(), newClass1, newClass1]
```

then you can check the frequency like below,

```
Collections.frequency(arrayList, newClass1);
```

If you are always adding new instance of Class1 then below will be the solution

```
[new Class1(), new Class2(), new Class1(), new Class1()]
```

override equals method in Class1 like below,

```
 @Override
public boolean equals(Object o){

    if(!(o instanceof Class1 )){
        return false;
    }else{

            return true;
    }
}
```

then in your test class,

```
System.out.println(Collections.frequency(array, new Class1()));
```

Comment: sadly its not but i loved your idea :) many thanks for the input - i was thinking / hoping along these lines too ... but wait actually on second thoughts i think I can change it to match this - yay, many many thanks - even though i was aware of Collections.frequency I had already discounted it but this post got me thinking :)

Comment: you're welcome! Please check my edited answer, i got solution for your new Class1 instances arraylist.

Comment: you should override equals() method in all your Class1, Class2... classes

Comment: It seems like a very bad idea to override `equals` to make all instances of the class to be equal.

Comment: If you want to find instance of Class1 then override equals only in Class1

Comment: accepting this answer - both this answer and top voted answer work but this answer is extremely original and well explained - many thanks to all - PS the 2 approaches detailed in this answer work - i however implemented [newClass1, new Class2(), newClass1, newClass1] using singletons in a scenario where it made sense to use singletons. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You could iterate through the ArrayList and check using the `instanceof` operator.

```
for (Object e : lst)
{
  if (e instanceof Car)
  {
    carCount++;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer - hoping for something a bit cleverer OR more efficient but your answer is much appreciated

Comment: There really isn't a more efficient way, unless you keep a running count while you're creating the list.  By the way, `instanceof` will be `true` for objects of classes that extend `Car`, as well as `Car` itself.  If that isn't what you want, then make it `if (e.getClass() == Car.class)`.

Comment: @danday74 there's not going to be anything more efficient, and almost certainly not anything "cleverer."  Not in Java 7.

Comment: @ajb - thanks, i liked your idea to keep a tally as you add items

Comment: @danday74: keeping tally may be just unnecessary complication (read: source of errors, increased cost of maintenance). How big is your list? How long can it take to count things?

Comment: i was hoping collections.frequency might be able to help - but apparently not sadly - o well there's some great ideas here - much appreciated all

Comment: `Collections.frequency` isn't any more efficient than if you or I wrote it.  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.frequency%28java.util.Collection%2Cjava.lang.Object%29

Comment: In fact, it has to call the `equals` methods, which is surely slower than an `instanceof` operation.

Answer (score 2):

You can need to check the class at any given position in the array by using  the keyword `instanceof`

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Number[] myN = new Number[5];
    
    //populate... ignore this if  want
    for (int i = 0; i < myN.length; i++) {
        if (i%2==0) {
            myN[i]= new Integer(i);
        }else{
            myN[i]= new Double(i);
        }
    }
    int classACounter=0;
    int classBCounter=0;
    //check
    for (int i = 0; i < myN.length; i++) {
        if (myN[i] instanceof Integer){
            System.out.println(" is an int");
            classACounter++;
        }
        if (myN[i] instanceof Double){
            System.out.println(" is a double");
            classBCounter++;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("There are "+classACounter+" elements of the class A");
    System.out.println("There are "+classBCounter+" elements of the class B");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, You can easily filter them by

```
result = Iterables.filter(collection, YourClass.java);
```

then you can apply `.size()` on the result.